# How to show image in react helmet programmatically with Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm using Gatbsy for my frontpage and I'm trying to add some meta data programmatically with react-helmet.

I have a SEO component as follows:

```
const SEO = ({title, description, location, image_url}) => {
    const capitalize = string => {
        if (string !== undefined){
            return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
        }

        return string

    };

    const MAIN_TITLE = settings.META_TITLE;
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <title>{`${MAIN_TITLE} | ${capitalize(title)}`}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={description}/>
            <meta property="og:title" content={`${MAIN_TITLE} | ${capitalize(title)}`}/>
            <meta property="og:description" content={description}/>
            <meta property="og:image" itemProp="image" content={image_url !== undefined ? image_url : `${settings.ROOT_URL}/static/image-cover-1e01617fb26211f1cd8e3dd24977070d.jpg`}/>
            <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
            <meta property="og:url" content={location.href}/>
            <meta property="twitter:title" content={`${MAIN_TITLE} | ${capitalize(title)}`}/>
            <meta property="twitter:description" content={description}/>
            <meta property="twitter:image" itemProp="image"  content={image_url !== undefined ? image_url : `${settings.ROOT_URL}/static/image-cover-1e01617fb26211f1cd8e3dd24977070d.jpg`}/>
            <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
        </Helmet>
    )
};

export default SEO
```

And I use it in one of Gatsby's pages as follows:

```
<div className="flex flex-col overflow-x-hidden min-h-screen">
     {loading && !hasError && <LoadingIndicator/>}
     {!loading && hasError && <div className="container my-12"><ErrorIndicator/></div>}
     {!loading && !hasError && <React.Fragment>
             <SEO title={`${vehicle.make} ${vehicle.model} ${vehicle.type}`}
                  description={`${vehicle.make} ${vehicle.model} wacht op u.`}
                  location={location}
                  image_url={vehicle.images instanceof Array ? vehicle.images[0].uri : vehicle.images.uri}/>
              .... // Rest of the code
      <React.Fragment>}
</div>
```

When I check in the console in the  tag on localhost or on the server, I see what I should see:

[image]

But on Facebook I see something else. For image, for example I see:

```
og:image    http://my-site/static/image-cover-1e01617fb26211f1cd8e3dd24977070d.jpg
```

Facebook uses `else` statement  in `<meta property="og:image" ..../>` tag, but `image_url` is not undefined and in the console I see the correct url.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The OG docs don't show item prop as an attribute, but I don't think that's it.

https://ogp.me/

What I think it is is that your code adds the meta programmatically, so on first load it's not there and Facebook's bots don't catch it? Try hard-coding that meta tag into the HTML to see if Facebook accepts that, and that will at least let you know if this is the issue or not.

Edit: sorry that doesn't really answer the root question. If the above turns out to be the problem I would suggest adding it programmatically on the server side if possible. You could try templating it in with something like EJS. Essentially I think you just need to make sure it's in the DOM early enough for Facebook's bots.

Edit: Facebook simply does not support (any longer) custom sharing. It's OG or nothing, and they take the OG from your raw html before your JS has a chance to change it. It's just not suitable for a SPA. You can Google OG for SPA and some people have come up with hacky proxies, but they're not good for your SEO.

Sorry :/

Comment: Your first statement is correct. The question is, how to solve it?

Comment: To solve that: where do you get the vehicle information for the meta? Is it from the URL, is it a SPA, are you using a CMS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Strapi as backhend and those vehicles are coming from Strapi.

Comment: Your app doesn't know which vehicle to display until it gets to the client side. So Facebook can't know which vehicle either. The work around is complicated, if you are serving static pages you need to splice a meta tag into the HTML before serving the HTML. For example GET route '/index.html' in the endpoint you would use fs.readFileSync to read the HTML as a string, and replace the meta values with content from your Strapi object. Your setup isn't really conducive to OG.

Comment: Simply: meta goes on each page, and you've made a *single* page application. Correct me if I'm wrong about your setup.